# markdown conflict in mako?

Tags: python, html, markdown, mako

In a Mako template, `##` is intended to comment out anything that is not to appear in the output.

But in Markdown, `##` means sub-heading, `###` means sub-sub-heading, etc.

Now applying a Markdown filter in Mako, isn't it obvious that there is a conflict?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd be using Markdown with Mako. Can you describe your use case?

Comment: So what exactly are you asking? (Is there an answer other than "Yes" that we can give you?)

Comment: @JeffBridgman I am trying to write h3, h4, etc. in a Mako template using markdown for more easy-to-read format, hence my question above. But anyway, it is fine as long as I switch back to HTML.

Comment: @Chris I am using markdown for better formatting on the back end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only in the Mako template itself is `##` a comment. You can still use variables (e.g., `${x}`) that are strings that contain hash characters without worrying they'll be interpreted as comments.

According to [Mako Syntax](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/syntax.html#comments):

> Above, the string representation of x is applied to the template’s output stream.

The variable is sent directly to the output.

It's the same concept of having hash characters in a Python string. For example:

```
s = "#This would be a Python comment"
print(s) # returns "#This would be a Python comment"
```

Comment: This does not work if you load a template from a file